# Android: missing data from AssetStream? (read MIDI data is inaccurate)

Tags: android, stream, midi, assets

I'm wanting to read MIDI data from an asset stream. The file is a MIDI0 file of length 150 bytes according to Windows. Using this code, I read 150 bytes measured by count, but the output string is only 127.5 bytes.

```
        try {
            assetStream = assets.open("MIDI0_7.mid");
            int count=0;
            do {
                byteValue = assetStream.read();
                count++;
                outputString = outputString + Integer.toHexString(byteValue);               
            } while (byteValue > -1) ;
            Log.d("MUSIC", "Final string " +outputString);
            Log.d("MUSIC", "bytes read " +count);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This read HEX data also doesn't match with the MIDI spec AFAICT. The opening 8 bytes should read

```
4d 54 68 64 00 00 00 06
```

but I get

```
4d 54 68 64 00 06
```

I can't be sure about the save format of my MIDI file (exported test file with 7 notes from Cakewalk SONAR) so I'm not sure why the MIDI doesn't correspond with the standards, but before I can solve that I need to know where my missing data is! What am I doing wrong to see some bytes getting dropped from my output stream?

Edit:
Okay, found it. Bytes less than 16 are returned as a single character by Integer.toHexString() instead of being a 0x figure. Easily fixed.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer on your question, so that others with the same problem can easily find it.

Comment: Would do but I need 100 reputation to answer my own questions, so I can only edit in the answers for the time being.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that.  Fair enough.